# How can get list of field value from all objects list in django python?

Tags: python, django

I have Client class, and i am trying to get all objects email in one list.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client_name = models.Char Field(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    client_email = models.Email Field()
```

From all objects list i need all emails which are in Client list. How can i do this ?

like...
list1 = [a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com, ...]

Comment: What is *Client list* here? How does it look like?

Comment: [{client_name:'abc", client_email: abc@gmail.com}, {client_name:'def", client_email: def@gmail.com},]      i need only, Client_email = [abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand about the question, I believe this is what you what

```py
all_objects = Client.objects.all()
all_email = []
for i in all_objects:
    all_email.append(i.clent_email)
```

or with a list comprehension

```py
all_objects = Client.objects.all()
all_email = [i.client_email for i in all_objects]
```

For django orm you can use

```py
all_email = Client.objects.values_list('client_email', flat=True)
# to convert to a list just do the following
all_email = list(all_email)
```

Comment: yes what i need is this but,is for loop is better practice to use?

Comment: you can use list comprehension

Comment: accept this answer if it solves your problem

Comment: i'm waiting for other who answer using ORM query :)

Comment: how do you feel about this answer now?

Comment: this return objects lists like : <QuerySet [<Client: rYpgqvLU2y6h>, <Client: yJE9mkfEK2RZ>, <Client: HBqYALjBaYyw>, <Client: z44HWokIktgd>, <Client: QibaYK7bElBA>, <Client: 25XDhtKkY3w7>, <Client: xWidTGaZDn83>, <Client: PWxIthwBA6m7>, <Client: Q3TkOLsZtgmU>, <Client: sjKsiAOUgXfl>]>

Comment: did you use values_list

Comment: Client.objects.values_list('client_email', flat=True) like this

Comment: yes it gives all email in queryset. then how can i store these in list? do you have any idea?

Comment: just do list(all_email). i'll update the same in the answer

Comment: are you doing that in the same way as shown in the answer

Comment: try to do this list(Client.objects.values_list('client_email', flat=True))

Comment: yes, 
TypeError: 'QuerySet' object is not callable

Comment: i don't know how you are getting type error: QuerySet object not callable. You should provide the code for what you are doing.

Comment: >>> all_email
<QuerySet ['kjohnson@miranda.info', 'ulynch@yahoo.com', 'robin53@gmail.com', 'brownrachel@gmail.com', 'shane37@hotmail.com', 'laurencollins@mcintyre-harding.com', 'kelly56@carrillo.org', 'lperry@yahoo.com', 'danielharris@yahoo.com', 'igarcia@coleman.biz']>
>>> list1 = list(all_email)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'QuerySet' object is not callable. ------- i dont know but this is correct we can change like this.

Comment: yes it works thanks, are you use whatsapp ?